# error unmarshalling when using fargate service deploy

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Not sure why I an getting this error from
`fargate service deploy -f docker-compose.yml`

```
[!] error unmarshalling docker-compose.yml
strconv.ParseFloat: parsing "": invalid syntax
```

There do not appear to be values in the docker-compose.yml file causing this syntax error. None of the KEY: 'VALUE' pairs are blank.

Sample docker-compose.yml format.

(environment values omitted and AWS account # omitted):

```
version: "3"
services:
  app-name:
    build: ../../../
    image: ############.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/app-name:0.3.7
    ports:
    - "443:5000"
    environment:
      KEY: 'VALUE'
    env_file:
    - hidden.env
```

hidden.env format:
`KEY=VALUE`

Comment: This appears to be related as well - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68367588/pycharm-cant-parse-docker-compose-yml-to-add-python-interpreter-seems-to-be-us

(I am using pycharm)

Answer (score 0):

The Docker cask on Homebrew defaults to enabling the "Use Docker Compose V2" Experimental Feature.

I ran `docker-compose disable-v2` and am no longer running into this error.

I was running Docker Desktop with `Compose v2.0.0-beta6`. After disabling version 2 I am now running with `Compose 1.29.2`